# How to use jpeg stream from IP Webcam app as src in html5 video tag?

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, html5-video

I'm using the IP Webcam android app to essentially stream video from my phone's camera to a webpage. When I try to set the src attribute in the video tag to the app's localhost to see the video stream I get an error.

```
<video autobuffer controls autoplay>
  <source id="mp4" src="http://[Phone's IP]:8080/browserfs.html" >
</video>

NOTE: I've tried using http://[Phone's IP]:8080/video and 
http://[Phone's IP]:8080/video.mp4 as the value for src as well
```

The response headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0
Connection:close
content-length:31979
content-type:image/jpeg
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:IP Webcam Server 0.2
```

I know that IP Webcam is basically sending a bunch jpeg images as shown in the response header I posted. I'm not sure what to do to get this to play as a video. No matter what I put as the extension I get:

```
http://[Phone's IP]/video.mp4 404 (Not Found)
```

Please help,  I'm burnt out and frustrated.

Comment: Tried url without a file name `http://[Phone's IP]:8080/` ? Response type appear to be "image/jpeg"

Comment: No that didn't work.

Comment: If type "http://[Phone's IP]:8080/browserfs.html" into address bar, what is resulting document ?

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Android Webcam Server</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquerymin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ipwebcam.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body { margin: 0 }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(loadBrowserFullscreen);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="img1" onclick="swBAspect()" src="/video" alt="Video feed"/>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Does `img` display webcam ?

Comment: By the look of it, yes. I assumed that a video tag was being used but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

So i had identical problem: "/videofeed" is your go to.
I viewed the html served by IP Webcam using 'view-source:'
prefix. works for 'IP phone Camera' as well , probably same  library for creating urls

Answer (score 0):

Try to set video stream using Javascript **navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia**
Change your browser camera to **MJPEG Camera**

```
<video autoplay></video>

<script>
var video = document.querySelector('video');

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(function(mediaStream) {
    video.srcObject  = mediaStream;
});
</script>
```

If ***MJPEG Camera*** get not listed in browser, try to setup it using http://ip-webcam.appspot.com/